# PHP Script to connect to MYSQL Database is not working

Tags: php, mysql, database

So here is my code:

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "kat";
$password = "";
$db_name="test";


$conn = mysqli_connect($servername ,$username, $password, $db_name);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected Successfully"

?>
```

This is the error it gives as i run (without debugging if that's useful to you):

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in C:\Users\katle\OneDrive\Desktop\CTU Stuff\My own projects\phpbackend\insert.php:8 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Users\katle\OneDrive\Desktop\CTU Stuff\My own projects\phpbackend\insert.php on line 8